# svn: Programmatically handle a custom property to track RCS-style self-increasing revision number?

Tags: svn, versioning, pre-commit-hook

The Foundation I work for use Subversion and RCS (git and hg are not an option) to track changes in some document-only projects.

For the projects under Subversion, I would like to keep track of [revisions per-file in a RCS-like style](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/rcs.html#RCS-file), i.e. `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3`, etc.

I though a nice way to do that would be to programmatically set a svn file-only [custom property](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html), to track RCS-style revision number, probably with a [`pre-commit hook`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html)?

I am not a programmer though. Could I please have some advice on how to do that, possibly with `sh` or `perl`? Python would be fine too, but I would need to ask to have it installed just for this.

Comment: Did you read this? https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.forcvs.revnums
Why do you want this? I think it's an XY-problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I read all the manual, we have been using svn since early 2000. No, I do not believe it is a XY-problem, I need to use svn, but I wish to keep RCS-style versions for each document. I could track that manually, but I would prefer to do it idiomatically within svn, if possible at all.

Comment: So is it only a personal preference without any "technical" reason?

Comment: It is team-related. I am not sure if that would be deemed "technical". We have several thousand text-only documents, which are rarely edited. Team (all made by volunteers with no technical skills, mostly working in Humanities) would greatly benefit by seeing at a glance RCS-style revision numbers per-document. At the moment, this is done manually.

Comment: So if anyone commit a change you increase manually RCS-revnum in a property? Is the property good solution for you? And you need "only" an automatism?

Comment: No, for now there is no custom property. The RCS-revnum is updated manually, within each file. I am looking for pointers on how to code a simple script, to be invoked with the pre-commit hook, so we can do this programmatically. PS: I will consolidate all these notes in the main question. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Understand. Do you need an RCS-file or only the generated revision number?

Comment: The generated revision number would be the minimum, but, wow, having the RCS-file would be absolutely astounding for us. I didn't even think it possible. We would have the best of both worlds.

Comment: About RCS-file: I think it's possible to generate it from `svn log`. The `svn log` has `--xml` so with a XML-tool is possible.